# error pops up on phonegap push notification plugin and pushwoosh.com

Tags: cordova, push-notification, xcode4.3, phonegap-plugins

I am implementing the push notification plugin for phonegap using the pushwoosh.com service. I followed this tutorial... http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/

After having some trouble with my provisioning profile and getting past that error, I now get an "alert" error when I run my app. Here is a screenshot of the error...[image]

I don't see anything about that error when I google it. I have gone over my code several times and don't see anything that stands out as "wrong". I am hoping someone else on here has had this problem and solved it somehow.

Comment: hi! is it possible to use push notification in phonegap without using third party app?

Comment: I haven't found anything in the phonegap framework that handles push notifications without a third party app.

Comment: You still need the backend for push notifications. There are several cross platform Push Providers like: Pushwoosh, Urban Airship, Xtify. They have different pricing models: freemium (unlimited notifications, premium features for paid customers only) or have limited number of push notifications (you have to pay if you want to send more than specific number of notifications).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an error. This is debug alert, which shows you that your device has successfully subscribed to push notifications. You can remove all debug alerts by removing all lines in index.html like this:

navigator.notification.alert(...)

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. App is working fine now. Thanks for your reply.